# USB Debugging: PC doesn't recognize that my Moto E (2nd Gen)(Upgraded to Marshmallow) in on debugging mode

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rooting, usb-debugging, motorola-moto-e, android-pc

So I'm trying to root my Moto E (2nd Gen) using PC apps such as Kingo Root, One Click Root etc. But the problem is that my PC doesn't recognize that my phone is in debugging mode. Moreover on my Android the following dialog box appears:[image]

Please help me.
I have installed the Android drivers on my PC.

Comment: Maybe get rid of the app that shows this popup?

Comment: Thanks for the reply iBug, but this pop-up pops up when I enable  USB debugging.

Comment: It's probable a builtin app that can be removed only if you have root access. Anyway it's not an Amdroid's feature

Comment: Ironic. I want to enable debugging to to root my phone.

Comment: No offense, but why are you trying to root with exploit apps? The Moto E series is incredibly easy to root using "official" documented methods... Unlock the bootloader using Moto's official website, flash or boot a supported version of TWRP, and then just flash SuperSU or Magisk and reboot and enjoy without all the King(o) spyware.

Answer (score 1):

> The USB Mobile Monitor allows you to connect your Android mobile phone
>   or tablet to your PC with a simple USB Cable. All that is required is
>   the download of the **USB Mobile Monitor App** on your device and the
>   installation of the USB Mobile Monitor software on your PC.
>
> The USB Mobile Monitor allows you to replace the keyboard, mouse and
>   computer screen of your PC with a single device.

---

Source: http://www.usbmobilemonitor.com/home.html

This is a kind of built-in system shipped with your device I guess. So,I think you need to install the APK version to get this works. It can be found [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amyuni.usbmobilemonitor). Then follow the usage on [this page](http://www.usbmobilemonitor.com/usage.html).

After that, try enabling USB Debugging again.

For the rooting part, follow this [guide](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-root-the-moto-e-2015-and-unlock-the-bootloader-xda-tv/) on XDA Developers.

Answer (score 0):

Try factory resetting, then attempt a root with direct flashing through ADB.  Probably would work better, and if you're rooting then you'll lose all your data anyway.

Cheers,

Neveraht.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings → About phone, tap Build number field 7 times.  You will begin seeing a message as you approach the 7 touches as shown below.

Ater that hit the back button and scroll down and enable usb debugging mode